# About javascript events and how do they work

Tags: javascript, html, events

First of all I am very bad at HTML/CSS/Javascript, I am just trying to pass my exams. I have the following piece of code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Practice for exam</title>

<style>

.rectangle{
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:10px;
}

</style>

<script>

window.onload=function(){

  for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {

    var div=document.createElement("div"); 
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.className="rectangle"; //div.classList.add("rectangle");
    div.innerHTML="divul " + (i+1);

  //  div.style.height="100px";
  //  alert(typeof(div.style.height));
    var initial= parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(div).height); 

    div.onclick=function(event){ //click div
      if(this.style.height!==""){
        var curent=parseInt(this.style.height);
         this.style.height= curent+10+'px';
       }
       else
      {
          this.style.height= initial + 10 + 'px';
      }
      event.stopPropagation(); 
    }
  }
  document.body.onclick=function(){ //click body
    var divuri=document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle");
    for(d of divuri) d.style.height=initial +'px';
  }
}
</script>

</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

That creates a html page, which has 10 rectangles, and if you click on one of them it's height increases by 10px; If you click anywhere else, in the 'body', the rectangles get back to their initial size. My question is, why was necessary to create a function(event) for increasing the divs size

```
div.onclick=function(event)
{ //click div
     if(this.style.height!==""){...
```

and not for resizing them to the intitial size

```
  document.body.onclick=function(){ //click body
    var divuri=document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle");
    for(d of divuri) d.style.height=initial +'px';
  }
```

What is the difference ?
And event.stopPropagation(), what does it really do?
The code is given by my teacher (it is public, she is ok to share it for sure), and I don't get why she did proceed like that and why that's correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why was it necessary to create a `function(event)` for increasing the divs size ... and not for resizing them to the initial size?

I suppose the focus in this question is on `event`, as for resizing to the initial size we also have a function. The difference is the parameter `event` which is lacking in the second function.

There are a few things to understand here:

- At the time the event happens, the `event` object is passed to the actual function call as argument, whether that function has defined the parameter or not. As we can see in the code for the second function: it doesn't use the event object in its body/code. This is the reason why it does not mention `event` in the function's parameter list. It could have done so, but why add it there, when the code has no use for it?
- The click event bubbles up. In other words: when an element is clicked, not only will that element receive the click event; also its parent element will receive it after that, and its grandparent after the parent received it, ... All its ancestor elements will receive the event, including the `body` element, in that "upwards" order.
- The first function uses the `event` object for one purpose: to call `stopPropagation`. This propagation is what is described in the previous bullet point. If it wouldn't call `stopPropagation`, the click event would bubble up, and it would reach the `body` element, where the click event will trigger the *second* function, immediately reducing the squares to their initial size! This would effectively cancel the effect we wanted to achieve (grow the size of a rectangle). To avoid that from happening `stopPropagation` is called: now there will be no other ancestors -- higher up in the hierarchy -- that will receive this click event.

Answer (score 0):

```
div.onclick=function(event)
```

is for clicking the created div, which was the rectangles

which is this code right here

```
 var div=document.createElement("div"); 
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.className="rectangle"; //div.classList.add("rectangle");
    div.innerHTML="divul " + (i+1);
```

whereas this line of code

```
document.body.onclick=function()
```

is triggered when clicking anywhere on the body of the page, executing the line of codes inside of it which resets the size back to initial

as for the

```
event.stopPropagation()
```

The stopPropagation() method of the Event interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases. It does not, however, prevent any default behaviors from occurring; for instance, clicks on links are still processed. This prevents any parent event handlers from being executed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this for yourself. Run it with `stopPropagation` commented out and see how it affects the result.

```js
window.onload=function(){

  for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {

    var div=document.createElement("div"); 
    document.body.appendChild(div);
    div.className="rectangle"; //div.classList.add("rectangle");
    div.innerHTML="divul " + (i+1);

  //  div.style.height="100px";
  //  alert(typeof(div.style.height));
    var initial= parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(div).height); 

    div.onclick=function(event){ //click div
      if(this.style.height!==""){
        var curent=parseInt(this.style.height);
         this.style.height= curent+10+'px';
       }
       else
      {
          this.style.height= initial + 10 + 'px';
      }
      console.log("clicked rectangle")
      //event.stopPropagation(); 
    }
  }
  document.body.onclick=function(){ //click body
    var divuri=document.getElementsByClassName("rectangle");
    for(d of divuri) d.style.height=initial +'px';
    console.log("clicked body")
  }
}
```

```css
.rectangle{
  width:100px;
  height:150px;
  border:1px solid red;
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:10px;
}
```

Comment: So if comment out 'event.stopPropagation', when I click on rectangle, the click is seen as a click on the body too and that's why It seems like it does nothing, because it resizes the rectangle everytime I click on a rectangle (document.body.onlick is triggered) ?

Comment: @Johnny Exactly. You need to stop the event from bubbling up to other elements, so if you stop propagation it will not bubble up to the body.